# How to change drum pads pressure sensitivity in Novation Impulse 61 Midi Keyboard

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I bough new Novation Impulse 61 Midi keyboard. I am unable to find a settings to change drum pads pressure sensitivity on it. I did once but forgot how. Can anyone help me to find the settings on it?

Comment: The users manuals can be found here (https://customer.novationmusic.com/en/support/downloads?brand=Novation&product_by_type=488&download_type=user-guides), but I don't find information about how to do what you're asking. Possibly it's a setting at the signal receiving end?

Comment: I have already check in doc but couldn't find anything explicit for it.

Comment: In that case, I would check at the receiving end. Perhaps there are signal threshold settings there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but a bit long for a comment.

---

If your keyboard is MIDI, changing the signal at the receiver end as @Aaron suggested is always possible, and likely the best you can do if you are not satisfied with the velocity curve. However, keep in mind that doing so will reduce the velocity precision: velocity in MIDI is encoded on values between 0 and 127, and the drumkit is expecting values in this range. In a mathematical point of view, you cannot map 0-127 to 0-127 with a monotonic function *and* covering all the values if you are not using the identity function.

As a naive example, if you want the pad to be more sensible, you could think you multiplying the value given by the pad by 2. If you do so:

- the receiver part will never receive any even values, you will jump from velocity 0 to velocity 2 without any steps in between,
- all values above 64 will be mapped to 127 thus losing any kind of variations in the high velo range.

This is perhaps what you want, but in my opinion it is always a good thing to remember this when mapping MIDI values ;).

### Edit:

After looking at the [manual](https://fael-downloads-prod.focusrite.com/customer/prod/s3fs-public/downloads/impulse-user-guide_0.pdf), end of page 19, you can change the velocity curve of the pads. I retain the original answer in case you want to do it on the receiver end.